# DOCTYPE is not rendered if declared in PHP include?

Tags: php, html, include, doctype, quirks-mode

So far i've declared for example

```
>test.php
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
```

and in index.php

```
>index.php
include 'test.php';
...
```

Works fine on all except IE8, as far as I know, will render the document in quirksmode. Any idea why?

Comment: Do the exact same HTML code work if in a local HTML document on your computer?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Is the Doctype the very first thing to appear? Check for any [byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) too.

Comment: @Phil - Your comment should probably be an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. From debugger and generated source it looks perfectly normal just without the doctype. Local or not it does not work i've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Check if `<!doctype html>` is not the first line; this will trigger quirks mode
- Check if the encoding is UTF-16; this requires a byte order mark
- Check the file encodings of the HTML documents to make sure they match
- Flush the buffer to output the doctype

**References**

- [Quick Guide to UTF-8](https://annevankesteren.nl/2004/06/utf-8)
- [Speed Up Your Website With PHP Buffer Flushing](http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-web-pages-php-buffer-flush/)
- [PHP5 Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php)
- [The Notepad file encoding problem, redux](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing this issue, but you've troubleshooted using the 4 points listed in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19261606/6111540) with no luck, then you might have overlooked what I did:

Double-check that any includes which come before the `include` containing `<!DOCTYPE html>` do not output HTML themselves.

Turns out I was accidentally trying to output some `script` and `link` tags in an earlier `include`. As a minimal example:

**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
```

**oops.php**

```
...
<script src="vendor/thing.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/thing.css">
...
```

**index.php**

```
include 'oops.php';
include 'test.php';
...
```

Comment: This is what the first bullet point in the answer you reference says to check for.

Comment: @Quentin The way I interpreted it was, the first line in test.php should be `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, which it is. It led me down a BOM rabbit-hole thinking there must be a hidden character or something. My answer gives a specific example of how previous includes could be outputting HTML before the doctype.